# Groovy: Is there any mechanism to caste groovy.json.internal.LazyMap to groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

Tags: groovy

In my project we were previously using **groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild** for application/xml content type response from REST API.

Now we want to support application/json content type response from REST API. For application/json content type response **groovy.json.internal.LazyMap** class is there in groovy.

The **groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild** class is used in many classes. If I can convert  groovy.json.internal.LazyMap to **groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild** then my job will be easy.

Is there any way to convert to **groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild** from **groovy.json.internal.LazyMap**.

If there is a better way to do the same please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937254/convert-json-to-xml-using-groovy) to convert the JSON to XML and re-slurp it.

However, this smells a bit...It sounds like you're basically passing XML around internally. It's probably cleaner to write a DTO/POGO that you pass around internally, and then localize serializers/deserializers at the boundary of your app where it needs to speak JSON/XML/other to other services. This will make supporting future interchange formats a question of "how do I get these 8 fields I need out of this payload to build my object" instead of "how can I transform formatX into XML".